# Problem while getting the original filename of a windows app with GetFileVersionInfo and VerQueryValue API

Tags: c++, windows, windows-10-desktop

I'm testing GetFileVersionInfo and VerQueryValue functions to get the original filename(OriginalFilename) of a file on Windows 10(64bits, version 1803).

I could get an original filename of some applications such as cmd.exe, putty.exe.

My problem is if i apply those functions to windowsapp, the VerQueryValue funtion never return.

One of the tested application is calculator(calculator.exe) that was located on "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WindowsCalculator_10.1804.911.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\Calculator.exe".

After changing security properies of the directory was the same rsults.

The results was same even though copying the Calculator.exe in Windowsapp to another directory(e:\aa\Calculator.exe).

Here is my code:

```
struct LANGANDCODEPAGE {
    WORD wLanguage;
    WORD wCodePage;
 } *lpTranslate;

VOID readFileInfo(LPWSTR fullName, LPWSTR infoStr)
{
    DWORD dwHandle;
    wprintf(L"read info from %s\n", fullName);

    DWORD dwinfoSize = GetFileVersionInfoSize(fullName, &dwHandle);
    if (!dwinfoSize) return;

    LPWSTR info = (LPWSTR)calloc(1, dwinfoSize);
    printf("info size: %u\n", dwinfoSize);

    if (info) {
        BOOL bRes = GetFileVersionInfo(fullName, 0, dwinfoSize, info);

        if (bRes) {
            UINT uLen;
            UINT uBytes;
            LPBYTE lpBuffer = NULL;

            if (VerQueryValue(info, L"\\VarFileInfo\\Translation", (LPVOID *)&lpTranslate, &uLen)) {
                if (uLen) {
                    WCHAR buf[1024] = { 0 };
                    swprintf(buf, L"\\StringFileInfo\\%04x%04x\\%s", lpTranslate[0].wLanguage, lpTranslate[0].wCodePage, infoStr);

                    wprintf(L"VerQueryValue Len: %d\n", uLen);
                    VerQueryValue(info, buf, (LPVOID*)&lpBuffer, &uBytes); //never return !!!!!!!!!!!!!!

                    wprintf(L"%s is %s\n", infoStr, (LPWSTR)lpBuffer);
                }
            }
        }

        free(info);
        info = NULL;
    }
}

int main()
{
    //ok(can get origianl filename)
    readFileInfo(L"C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe", L"OriginalFilename");

    //not ok(second VerQueryValue never retrun)
    readFileInfo(L"C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\Microsoft.WindowsCalculator_10.1804.911.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\\Calculator.exe", L"OriginalFilename");

    //not ok
    readFileInfo(L"E:\\aa\\Calculator.exe", L"OriginalFilename");

return 0;
}
```

please check what the problem is..
thanks.

The following file is that file....
[image]

Comment: "never return" - so it just hungs or what? what is the call stack? Do windows store apps even have a version info?

Comment: That file has no Windows resources at all. Those properties don't apply to Windows Apps as a right click - Properties - Details would have shown you.

Comment: VTT, yes hung. If i run a calculator from the start menu, windows executes the calculator.exe in the windows app direcotry(refer to the above picture).

Comment: That folder is sandboxed quite heavily.  The only accounts that have read access are TrustedInstaller and System.  With a secret backdoor for regular users so they can start programs from it.  That you can look at it with Explorer is already very fishy, messing with ownership is something you might well regret sooner or later.  Don't do it.

Comment: @Hans Passant, thank you for your advice.. yes, it was so heavy...

Comment: Please post the original code. Your code does not compile (the first call to readFileInfo has two commas without a parameter in between; and the includes are missing).

Comment: It doesn't matter, THERE ARE NO RESOURCES AT ALL IN THE FILE. Therefore there is NO VERSIONINFO. Therefore IT DOES NOT HAVE AN ORIGINAL NAME. If you want to know about it read its manifest files in same directory. Windows Apps ARE NOT Windows programs.

Comment: @CatCat thank you. after rebooting my computer, the problem dose not happen... the function returns an error that means "no original name"... i'll test it more...